# How to parse a string range in the format "yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd" to start/end date

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Im getting an string input like this `"yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd"` I want to create two Carbon instances `$from_date and $to_date` from that string.

Comment: Maybe `list($start, $end) = explode(' to '..`?

Comment: explode your string on "to", and the resultant array will contain the 2 dates, first being the start and second being the end date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could explode the string on `to` and map over it to return two Carbon instances. Finally, destructure the resulting array. For example:

```
$dates = "2019-01-21 to 2019-01-31"; 

list($from_date, $to_date) = array_map(function($date) {
    return Carbon\Carbon::parse($date); 
}, explode('to', $dates));
```

Here's also a working [example.](https://implode.io/yfD8CC)